# Am I destroying good variation when including seasonality in price/expenditure system?

Tags: regression

my data includes expenditure and I matched it with prices using a time variable which indicated months. If I were to run a regression (or an AIDS) of expenditure on prices and I include the variable containing months to control for seasonality, am I killing the price variation I just introduced?

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate on ',,matched it with prices using a time variable...'?

Comment: I have a variable containing the months when the expenditures were made. I used the months to match another dataset containing the price of the products in different months